# find a vector perpendicular to set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of $m$ vectors given by $$A =\left(\vec{v}_0,\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\ldots,\vec{v}_m\right),$$ elements of which need not be all linearly independent, in an $n$-dimensional space. I want a method that will give me a vector orthogonal to all of them.

I need a robust algorithm because I plan to use it for values of *n* which may go up to 100 and those of *m* to 600.

Comment: The common way to do this is dot products. Two vectors are perpendicular if their dot product is zero.

Comment: If $m\geq n$ then there might not be any vector orthogonal to all of them.

Comment: @Winther All the vectors in the set are not linearly independent, as I mentioned. So, even if $m\geq n$ there might be a solution, yes?.

Comment: @alice_v3.0.4 If $m > n$ then the set of vectors have to be lineary dependent. There might be yes, but generally one would not expect this (say if the vectors are randomly generated). For example if $n=3$ and all the $m$ vectors lie in the $xy$-plane then there will be a solution (any vector orthogonal to this plane).

Comment: Hi, I applied this with QR decomposition  (mentioned in the accepted answer below), and it always returns a vector of Zeros ( with a matrix of M,N  M>N. ) , it returns a vector of N zeros . I got the results same after using Numpy linalg.lstsq method.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solve $A^T \vec{x} = \vec{0}$. Any solution will do.

**UPDATE**

To do this numerically, you are welcome to use either LU or QR decomposition as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Can you please suggest any algorithm that will solve your equation for me?

Comment: @alice_v3.0.4 Yes, the standard one is Gaussian Elimination

Comment: @gt6989b Gaussian elimination is not reccomendable in general if the vectors are floating point numbers (apposed to integers) as rounding errors tend to be a big problem (see e.g [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29#Numerical_computation)). A [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) looks like a better option imo.

Comment: @Winther that depends if you want to program something or do it by hand. I would much rather to GE by hand than QR...

Comment: @Winther missed it -- updated the answer.

Comment: What if you get $\vec{x} = 0$ as the solution? How do I obtain a solution with non-zero $\vec{x}$?

Comment: @becko Gaussian elimination will only produce zero solution if there is no other one...

Answer (score 3):

Pick any vector, and then run the [Gram Schmidt orthogonolization process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) on the vector with respect to your set of vectors $A$ to get the desired vector

Comment: you will quite possibly get $\vec{0}$.

Comment: Hm, yes - good point. What if we start with $v_0 \times v_1$? I don't think there's anyway to escape getting a $0$ vector, the same thing might happen while solving the linear equation you provided right?

Comment: cross product only works in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but perhaps you know an extension. The only way you get 0 is when the matrix $A$ is full rank, sure it's not the same here -- unless your original vector is not in the row space, which is why i did not mention it in my answer... But likely, you are right (still, solving a linear equation is supposedly simpler that Gram-Schmidt, but I like your solution, +1)

Comment: What do you mean by"on the vector wrt your set"? Gram-Schmidt is run on a set of vectors not a single vector wrt a set of vectors as written. It only generates vectors that have the same span as the input set so if all input vectors are in some plane then the output vectors will be in the same plane (and it will give $0$ eventually). Thus it will fail for cases where all vectors are in a plane even though there exists vectors that are orthogonal to this plane.

Answer (score 1):

Why not solve the dot product system of the vector $\vec{x}$ dotted with each $m$ to yield $0$ and express it as a matrix?

Then for algorithm, you can choose LU factorization or any other method, taking around $n^2$ FLOPS $n$ being roughly $m$.

It's hard to see a much faster way to do that (in terms of FLOPS).

Comment: Thank you for the LU factorization suggestion.