# Definition from a paper - computation of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I found this definition in a paper:

[image]

So I know matrix $A$, which is rectangular and full column rank, and i want to understand how to numerically compute matrix $A^\perp$.
As a first trial I thought that it was the orthogonal complement of matrix $A$ hence I applied this function:

$$A^\perp=null(A^T)$$

but after the properties mentioned in the paper are not correct as well as the dimension of matrix $A^\perp$.

Edit: I also tried, based on a suggestion of a user to compute $A^\perp=pinv(A)$ but still the properties mentioned in the paper are not satisfied.

Any suggestions to compute $A^\perp$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a set of columns of $A$ which are independent (as $A$ has full column rank). Call these columns as $\{a_1,\dots,a_{m}\}$.
Then you want to find one more vector $v_1$ which is not a linear combination of these. So you may want to find a vector perpendicular to these. ie. $a_i^\top v =0\quad \forall i \in [m]$.

To get this $v_1$, solve $A^\top v_1 = 0$, using some choice of solver like LU algorithm, or QR decomposition algorithm.

Now add $v_1$ to this set of $\{a_1,\dots,a_{m}\}$, and repeat until you get $v_2$. Continue till you get all $\{v_1,\dots,v_{n-m}\}$, which constitute your new matrix $A^\perp$

Comment: Can you provide an example of your procedure to show its effectiveness? Best regards.

Comment: @it8, some references that may help: for theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#Numerical_computation for  computation with code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835246/how-to-solve-homogeneous-linear-equations-with-numpy and for a mathematical reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1767675/439353

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot I provide an answer as a reliable MATLAB code as well.

Answer (score 1):

The described properties of ${A^\perp}^T$ means exactly that its columns form an orthonormal basis of the perpendicular complement of the column space of $A$. Gram-Schmidt should get you there once you have *some* basis for the perpendicular complement.

Comment: So based on your suggestion I should try to compute $A^{\perp T}$ as orth(null(A')), correct?

Comment: The kernel of $A^T$ is the column space of ${A^\perp}^T$ (transpose both sides of $A^\perp A=0$ to see this most easily; rank considerations are necessary to conclude). And ${A^\perp}^T$ has orthonormal columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion of @Rahul Madhavan here I provide my MATLAB code to achieve the matrix $A^\perp$.

First just generate matrix $A$ that satisfies the properties in the paper. Secondly this is my code:

```
nc=size(A,1);
mc=size(A,2);

Vt=[];
Ai=A;
for i=1:nc-mc
    [s,v,d]=svd(Ai);
    numeig=size(v,2);
    vi=s(:,numeig+1);
    Ai=[Ai vi];
    Vt=[Vt vi];
end
Aperp=Vt';
```